# In Web.xml Getting error <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Tags: eclipse, web.xml

## In web.xml getting error  as

**Web.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="6.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee  https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd">

  <display-name>Logistic</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LogoutServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginValidate</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginValidate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.LoginValidate</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginValidate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginValidate</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Register</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.Register</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UserActivation</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UserActivation</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.UserActivation</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserActivation</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UserActivation</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>resetpassword</display-name>
    <servlet-name>resetpassword</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.resetpassword</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resetpassword</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resetpassword</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>StockServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>StockServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.StockServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StockServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/StockServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>StockServlet1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>StockServlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.StockServlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StockServlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/StockServlet1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>AddItem</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddItem</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.AddItem</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddItem</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddItem</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>AddCart</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddCart</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.AddCart</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddCart</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddCart</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>DelFromCart</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DelFromCart</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.DelFromCart</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DelFromCart</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DelFromCart</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>OrdersDB</display-name>
    <servlet-name>OrdersDB</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.OrdersDB</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OrdersDB</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OrdersDB</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Related files are unable to load Referenced file contains errors.
The errors below were detected when validating the file "jakartaee_10.xsd" via the file "web.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "jakartaee_10.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when jakartaee_10.xsd is validated in the context of web.xml.

**Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/C:/Users/JN/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas_1.2.600.v202307260543.jar!/
dtdsAndSchemas/jakartaee_10.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."**

[image: Check image to reference]

[image: Web.xml Error]

How to resolve the issue?